# Yosemite localhost MAMP start over

Tags: localhost, mamp

I'm trying to run MAMP so I can develop a wordpress site on localhost. I've made a mess of all my apache, php, mysql, phpmyadmin etc localhost configuration files on Yosemite. How do I delete everything so I can re-install MAMP and start over like it was a new computer?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up deleting all MAMP and MAMP pro folders, downloaded MAMP Pro Trial version and installed and then pressed "start servers" everything started. I then switched to MAMP (non pro) and my local host is now working fine. MAMP PRO must have reset everything for me correctly.